# How can I print an object with html entities php?

Tags: php, html-entities

I'd like to use `print_r` or `var_dump` to print out an object as it appears. However, there is html in properties of the object. You'd think `html_entity_decode` would help me here, but that only works on strings rather than entire objects.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: those functions are generally only for debugging, why don't you loop the object?

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't work for [`var_dump`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php), but [`print_r`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) takes a second argument that tells it to return the representation as a string instead of printing it. So you can do:

```
$rep = print_r($var, true);
echo '<pre>' . htmlentities($rep) . '</pre>';
```

For `var_dump()` you could use the [output buffering functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) to capture the output, then display it using [`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Answer (score 0):

Simply print an HTML `<pre>` tag before dumping the variable.

Comment: That prevents reformatting, it doesn't treat the contents as literals.